# How to subscribe two topic differently in Python

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I can not subscribe two topic at the same time with my code, can you recommend me some improvements

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqttclient
import time
from excel_adapter import excel_yaz
def subscribe_topic(topic, client_name):
    def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
        if rc == 0:
            print(f"{client_name} is connected")
            global connected
            connected = True
        else:
            print(f"connection failed for {client_name}")

    def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
        global MessageReceived
        print(f"{client_name}: {msg.topic} {str(msg.payload.decode('utf-8'))}")
        excel_yaz(str(msg.payload.decode("utf-8")))

        MessageReceived = True

    # mqtt broker codes:
    connected = False
    MessageReceived = False

    mqtt_port = 1883
    mqtt_broker = "xxxxxx"
    mqtt_username = "yyyyyy"
    mqtt_password = "111111"

    client = mqttclient.Client(client_name)
    client.username_pw_set(mqtt_username, password=mqtt_password)
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.on_message = on_message
    client.connect(mqtt_broker, port=mqtt_port)
    client.subscribe(topic)
    client.loop_forever()

    while connected != True:
        time.sleep(0.2)

    while MessageReceived != True:
        time.sleep(0.2)
```

When I use my code in main.py I can just connect Client1 but client2 can not be used. What should ı do my friends.

Comment: You shouldn't need multiple clients in a single application, a client can subscribe to an unlimited number of topics

Answer (score 0):

Create a single client and call `subscribe` multiple times.

Then your `on_message` handler can check which topic the incoming message belongs to.

Just a suggestion but I would instantiate the client external to that function and then pass it around as needed.